# Working on same git repo on two computers

Tags: git, web, cloud, synchronization, fileshare

I'm facing a problem that I'm trying to solve on the best possible way. I'm working on a project and it's hosted on GitHub. I have a desktop computer (home) and laptop that I get to work. When I'm home sometimes I just want to switch from one to another. There's virtualbox machine that keeps all configuration and services (nginx, mysql etc.).

My question is - if I put working directory on my dropbox/onecloud, what would happen? I know the file changes will be synced between two computers but I'm not sure what will happen with GIT repository there and is it even possible to keep virtualbox machine files on onecloud/dropbox ?

What are your thoughts? I know I can just push/pull every time I switch computers but I'm looking for a solution that thinks my two computers are actually single GIT repository?

So if I'm bored in my desktop chair and want to switch to a sofa with laptop - what would be best way to keep source code and VM in sync ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want to edit same github repo on different computers. I am using centOS for desktop and kalinux linux for laptop. Here are what I did: suppose you created a repo by using desktop (Which means you have already set up git ssh and so that you can push your work to github with no problems). Now you need generate ssh key in your laptop. (for linux, something like ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your same email address here". I believe you know how to generate ssh key. It is just same as what you did on your desktop) Then add the new ssh key to your github. After that you go to your repos (the one you want to edit) on your github and find the clone or download button copy the address and back to your laptop terminal command line (find which folder you want to download the repo to)and type git clone (paste the URL) press enter. The repo will fully loaded into the local folder. Then you can edit and use same command like git add, git commit, git push. You will see the changes in the same repo on the github.